# How to modify each element in a list without creating a new list

Tags: python, list, split

I want to modify all elements in a list such that I delete all characters after certain specific characters.

list is ['JACK\NAME1','TOM\NAME2'] and I want to modify it into ['JACK', 'TOM']

Right now I am using a For Loop with Split command:

```
text = ['JACK\\NAME1','TOM\\NAME2']

text_use = []

for item in text:
    item = item.split('\\',1)[0]
    text_use.append(item)

text_use
```

But I also have to create a new empty list (text_use) and append items to it.
Is there a better way to do this? Where I don't have to use a For Loop?

Or where I don't have to create an empty list and then append items to it?

Thank you

R

Comment: list comprehension

Comment: Do you want to avoid creating a new list entirely and modify `text` in place, or do you want to avoid the explicit `for` loop? Because those are different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, it's more idiomatic (pythonic) to use `enumerate`:

```
for i, item in enumerate(text):
    text[i] = item.split('\\',1)[0]
```

Comment: I don't mean to sound like i'm rooting for my answer, but how in the world is that more pythonic than list comprehension?

Comment: OP mentioned he didn't want to create a new list, which a list comprehension does

Comment: Technically, yes. But based on the "level" of the question, I'm pretty sure he meant he didn't want to define another variable with an empty list.

Comment: @SuperStew well, it is *correctly* doing what the OP asks, instead of *creating a new list* like a list comprehension... so there's that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that seems to be prioritizing the exact technical definition of what op said over what he meant.

Comment: @SuperStew or, you know, what the OP actually said. I cannot know what the OP *meant* if they say "without creating a new list". If that's what the OP asks, then this is clearly a duplicate anyway, and people should seek for clarification and an unambiguous problem statement rather than answering the question.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga some level of assumption based on context is necessary for basic communication. The alternative would be asking op to verify the exact meaning of every single word and phrase, which is silly. Again `But I also have to create a new empty list (text_use) and append items to it.` makes it pretty apparent

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
text = ['JACK\\NAME1','TOM\\NAME2']
text = [x.split('\\',1)[0] for x in text]
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i think it's pretty obvious that isn't what OP meant. `But I also have to create a new empty list (text_use) and append items to it.` is pretty clearly referring to him defining an empty list to append to, not the details of what happens in the background

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the list *positions* instead of the list *values*, and then access the items by their position in the list:

```
for pos in range(len(text)):
    text[pos] = text[pos].split('\\',1)[0]
```